# iOS UITableView like Sticky Header Index list for Flex Air

Tags: listview, apache-flex, android-listview, air, flex-spark

Does anyone know if there are existing tools out there for Adobe Flex (Air) that have the same behavior as the iOS's UITableView's sticky header for Spark List view ?

[image]

something like this, when you scroll down the sticky head will update to the corresponding label initial

Comment: I don't know of anything built in; but I don't think it would be hard to create something like this.  [And +1 for adding the screenshot]

Comment: yeah I ended up creating one myself, not that complicated :)

Comment: If you're able be sure to answer your own question and share your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you :  http://corlan.org/2011/07/04/creating-flex-mobile-section-lists/
You need to add/tweak some of the code to achieve what you want but this is a good basis